EXT4 FBE encrypted folder policy descriptor different from key descriptor
I have a directory encrypted with EXT4 file-system FBE on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
When I run
e4crypt get_policy [encrypted_directory]

It returns the correct policy descriptor. However, when I run
e4crypt add_key [encrypted_directory]

It returns the wrong key descriptor, does it mean the encrypted directory is corrupted?
